# How to get rid of these vertical lines in the editor

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I can't stand these little vertical and horizontal lines in my code that show code structure. I've disabled `Visual Guides` and `Indent Guides` in the settings but they're still visible. I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2.

Please help :-)

[image: Android Studio editor view]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable the **Show UI Guides for build methods** option in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Flutter:

[image: Show UI Guides for build methods]

Comment: I thought this didn't work.  If you search for guides in the Preferences section it shows Editor-General-Appearance setting and not Languages&F-Flutter setting.  That explains it!  I'll open my eyes a bit more next time!